# How would I find a LeMond head badge?

Tags: repair, used-bike

Looking to buy a used LeMond frameset. The price is right but it's missing its head badge. Anyone have advice about how I'd go about replacing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Politely - consider that the bike may be counterfeit or faked.  The price might be right but what if its something much crappier, tarted up to look right ?

Answer (score 2):

You could always keep an eye out on eBay for your LeMond head badge, or better yet create a "saved search" that will notify you by email when someone tries to sell one.  The other alternative is to search eBay, craigslist, the classified ads in the newspaper, and so on for another LeMond bike or frameset for sale, buy it, transfer the head badge or use the new bike/frame, and then sell the bike or frame that you don't intend to use.